# Random function selecting

Tags: python, function

A strange issue with my code.  Its asking the question 14 times when i only want 10 questions to be asked.  Then it is not calculating the score correctly either.  Any help appreciated to fix both of these issues!  Thanks in advance

```
import random
StudentName = input("Please enter you name: ")


def question_a():
    score=0
    num1=random.randint(1,10)
    num2=random.randint(1,10)
    num3=num1-num2
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(num1)+"-"+str(num2)+"? "))
    if answer==num3:
        print ("Well done, you  are correct")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print ("That is the wrong answer")

    return score

def question_b():
    score=0
    num1=random.randint(1,10)
    num2=random.randint(1,10)
    num3=num1+num2
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(num1)+"+"+str(num2)+"? "))
    if answer==num3:
        score = score + 1
        print ("Well done, you  are correct")
    else:
        print ("That is the wrong answer")

    return score

def question_c():
    score=0
    num1=random.randint(1,10)
    num2=random.randint(1,10)
    num3=num1*num2
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(num1)+"*"+str(num2)+"? "))
    if answer==num3:
        score = score + 1
        print ("Well done, you  are correct")
    else:
        print ("That is the wrong answer")

    return score


def question_d():
    score=0
    num1=random.randint(1,10)
    num2=random.randint(1,10)
    num3=num1/num2
    num4=round(num3,1)
    answer=float(input("What is "+str(num1)+"/"+str(num2)+"? "))
    if answer==num4:
        score = score + 1
        print ("Well done, you  are correct")
    else:
        print ("That is the wrong answer")

    return score

my_list=[question_a,question_b,question_c,question_d]

for i in range (0,10):
    random.choice(my_list)()

final_score = (question_a() + question_b() + question_c() + question_d())

print(StudentName+", you scored "+str(final_score)+"/10.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
random.choice(my_list)()
```

calls 10 random function: right. But ignores the output: wrong.

Then this line:

```
final_score = (question_a() + question_b() + question_c() + question_d())
```

calls these functions non-randomly and adds the results. 10 + 4 equals 14 calls to your functions.

Solution:

```
final_score = 0
for i in range (0,10):
    final_score += random.choice(my_list)()
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks so much Rodrigo, works!